# Email a copy of a completed form

Tags: php, jquery

I was asked to send out an email that is a copy of a completed form. Currently I use jquery to get the inner html related to the form and POST it to the PHP server. Unfortuantely Outlook 2007 does not render HTML like a browser does so its quite ugly. Is there a way to do this without creating a static HTMLdocument? There are at least 50 inputs and I'd like to avoid hardcoding values.

Comment: You're going to need to clarify that question... 
If you want a copy of the completed form, why do you need HTML?

Comment: Create a new text-only or HTML email on the server from the form fields. It's well-known that [Outlook doesn't render HTML like a modern browser](http://www.pinpointe.com/blog/email-campaign-html-and-css-support).

Comment: @rm-vanda This is true. You reminded me of the possibly of using tcpdf to create a PDF version of the form but that came out as crap too (after using HTML Tidy). Is there anything else I can use?

Comment: @UselessIntern what's wrong with the answers below? My answer sends *every* value from your form field (plus the field name) in a plain-text email, and rm-vanda's sends the actual form fields and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest (and laziest) way is to do something like this (no HTML)

```
// init the $message var
$message = '';

// loop through all form inputs
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $message .=  $key.': '.strip_tags($value)."\r\n";
}

// send the email
mail($to,$subject,$message);
```

Answer (score 0):

If hardcoding your values is the trouble, try something like this
 (assuming your boss wants an *exact* copy of the completed form...):

```
<?php 
$email= '<form>'; 
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
     $email .= '<input type="text" name="'.$key.'" value="'.$value.'" />'; 
}

mail("yourboss@some.com", "copy of form", $email); // or whatever mail function you prefer.
```